# How can I find the result of all these values combined?

Tags: python, list, function

So I'm trying to create a function `shoplan(prices: list[int], amount: int)` where the `amount` describes how much money I'm given and `prices` are the list of things I can buy within that list.
Moreover, **I'm only allowed to buy 2 things at max from the list**

So for instance,

- `shoplan([1,2], 1) == 1` because the amount I'm given is 1 and so, I can only buy one
- `shoplan([1,2,2,3,3,3], 10) == 6` because although I'm given 10, I can only buy 2 items, and the maximum I can get from adding two numbers is 6.
- `shoplan([1,1,1,3,5,5], 7) == 6` because although the maximum sum of the list is 10, I'm only given 7, and so, the maximum summation that either results or equals to 7 is 6, hence why 6 is the number.

Here is what I have btw...

```
def shoplan(prices: list[int], amount: int):
  for order in prices:
    if amount == order:
      return amount
    else:
      if sum(order) == amount:
        return amount
```

However, this doesn't work at all, so what changes should I make?

Comment: Consider this algorithm: Sort the price list from max to min, then find the first item that is smaller than `amount`. Then, if you have any money left, find the second item that can be purchased with the remaining amount.

Comment: I understand the first portion of ur explaination but I'm not sure I can follow the second portion.... can you please explain that in code terms?? Sorry for disturbing u btw.

Comment: Well, how would you solve the problem by hand? Imagine that you physically had the `10` (let's say $10) and walked into a store and saw items with those prices. What steps would you take in order to decide what you can buy?

Comment: Please write a more descriptive title. I'm thinking something like "How can I find the optimal set of numbers that sum to a given amount?" although that doesn't really cover the maximum size requirement (2).

Comment: What have you already tried? Your code covers the case where you can only buy one item, great, but what about buying two? Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) Even if this isn't homework per se, the advice still applies: "Search for already existing questions about your issue", "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first", and "Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation".